# Add if condition inside a CURSOR

Tags: oracle11g

I need to check relevant condition with SELECT statement. simply I need this.

```
if systemdate is 'Monday' then 
   select statement1(which contains cursor)
else 
   select statement 2(which contains cursor)
```

Here is my code:

```
CURSOR PR_CASHDEPOSITEMAIL IS
    SELECT      B.STR_DEALER_NAME AS DEALERNAME,
                B.STR_BC_BRANCH_CODE AS ASSINGBRANCH,
                A.STRDDH_DEALERCODE AS ICAMDEALERCODE,
                B.STR_DEALER_CODE AS DEALERCODE,
                TO_DATE(A.DTDDH_DPDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')AS RECEIPTDATE,
                A.NUMDDH_BALANCEAMOUNT AS RECEIPTAMOUNT,
                A.STRDDH_DPSLNO AS DEPOSITNUMBER 
    FROM        GLINFO.TBLDEALERDEPOSITEHEADER A ,
                ADL.REF_DEALER_MASTER B ,
                CORPINFO.TBLBRANCHES C
    WHERE       A.NUMDDH_BALANCEAMOUNT >0 
    AND         A.STRDDH_DEALERCODE=B.STR_COMP_DEALER_CODE
    AND         B.STR_BC_BRANCH_CODE=C.BRN_CODE
    AND         B.str_bc_branch_code =strBranch 
    ORDER BY    B.STR_BC_BRANCH_CODE, B.STR_DEALER_NAME, RECEIPTDATE, DEPOSITNUMBER;

BEGIN

--rest of code
```

I need to add previously mentioned condition to this select statement.

Comment: You have only one statement in your example. What is `statement1` and `statement2`?

Comment: statement 2 is same like statement 1. the difference is it only catches different date ranges

Answer (score 1):

Cursor with a parameter can help here. Cursor declaration:

```
CURSOR PR_CASHDEPOSITEMAIL (p_day varchar2) -- <-- parameter declaration
  IS
    SELECT <...>
    FROM   <...>
    WHERE  <...>
      and to_date(some_date_column, 'Day') = p_day; -- <-- parameter use in query
```

Use of cursor:

```
...
begin
  open PR_CASHDEPOSITEMAIL('Monday'); -- <-- passing value to the cursor
  ...
```